# Recovery when failover

Tags: postgresql, replication

**1/ Description:**

I have 2 Centos machine: master, slave (*streaming replication*). Both of them are built on PostgreSQL 9.3 (*image below*) and configured failover event ([failover PG 9.3 document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/warm-standby-failover.html)).

- Last WAL in master (pg_xlog): `0000000100000002000000D8`
- Last WAL in archive log folder in master: `0000000100000002000000D7`
- Last WAL in slave (pg_xlog):  `0000000100000002000000D5` (3 WALs latency between slave and master)  .
- recovery.conf   file in slave

  `standby_mode = 'on' 
  primary_conninfo = 'host=10.12.10.108 port=5444 user=enterprisedb password=123456 ' 
  trigger_file = '/tmp/failover' 
  restore_command = 'scp enterprisedb@10.12.10.108:/opt/archivelog/%f "%p"'`

Now (3 WALs latency slave & master), the master fails (shutdown by manual) then the slave begin failover procedures..

**2/ Questions:**

- Does slave miss 3 WALs(`0000000100000002000000D6, 0000000100000002000000D7, 0000000100000002000000D8`) or 1 WAL (`0000000100000002000000D8`) after failover ? Why ?
- If I copy all WAL in *pg_xlog* from *master* to *pg_xlog* in *slave* . Does slave miss WAL after failover? Why ?
- If I copy all WAL in *pg_xlog* from *master* to *pg_xlog* in *slave* (last WAL in slave: `0000000100000002000000D8` ) . How slave do a recovery when failover ?

[image]

**EDIT:**
 I am using **pgpool-II 3.4** to control failover between master-slave (failover_command in pgpool.conf).

Comment: Is this a real setup?  What happens when the host of the master goes completely down?  In this case, it appears, you cannot get the missing WALs in any way, which means you cannot really fail over to the slave.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i am using pgpool-II 3.4 to control failover. I will edit my post.

Comment: This post is my test. As my thinking, we have all history of WAL in both pg_xlog & archive log folder in master (except crash disk). So when failover, slave will restore from master's archive log folder (i know that), but if we copy several WAL files from master.pg_xlog to slave.pg_xlog  (latency case) , i do not know WAL files will restore or not when failover?

Comment: I tested with question 1 and slave miss 1 WAL (0000000100000002000000D8) because slave recover WAL in master's archive log folder and can not receive WAL streaming (master stopped).

Comment: With question 2 (if WAL is not crashed in master && latency = 3 WAL files), after copying WAL from master to slave, slave is started successfully because master.pg_xlog + master.archive_log save all WAL files and slave.pg_xlog is a part of them (i think) so when failover, slave will restore from master.archive_log (000...D5 -> 000.D7) & slave.pg_xlog (000...D8) which is copied from master.pg_xlog. (fix me if i am wrong-thanks)

Comment: I'll try with pg_rewind (http://hlinnaka.iki.fi/2013/05/23/pg_rewind-a-tool-for-resynchronizing-after-failover/)

Comment: If the `master` is isolated (network problem), I think I will shut down that cluster (in a period of time, depending on company's rules) because `consistent data` is very important (in this case, I think it's more vital than `availability`).  On the other hand, if the `master's disk` is broken, of course we need to recovery any possible WALs.  In this case, I think we can have a `stand-alone master` for backing up (taking resources a lot), it means these applications have to `write data` on both `masters`.